# Why in C++ we use SetCursorPos(10,20); instead of BOOL SetCursorPos(10,20); why it's throwing compilation errors?

Tags: c++

Why in C++ do we use `SetCursorPos(10,20);` instead of `BOOL SetCursorPos(10,20);`? Why is the second one throwing compilation errors? The MSDN specification says to use `BOOL` and it's not good why?

Comment: `BOOL SetCursorPos(10,20);` is a function-declaration. `SetCursorPos(10,20);` is a function-call. If you don't know the difference, then you might want to start with something more basic (like, learning the language from scratch).

Comment: ok thx : ) just new in c++

Comment: So start by learning the language, not by trying to implement a Windows application.

Comment: Here's some more difficult and practical question before recommended learning C++ handbook: when compiling SetCursorPos it compiles only when both #include <windows.h> and #include <iostream> are included. Compiling with only the first one throws errors but no I/O operations are used only one function call SetCursorPos(10,20); Why including iostream is needed?

Comment: Same answer as the one above...

Comment: @goodvibration: `BOOL SetCursorPos(10,20);` is a function declaration? Are you sure? Wouldn't it have to be `BOOL SetCursorPos( int, int );` to be a function declaration?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Yeah, you're right. Wasn't paying too much attention, as the question didn't look very well organized and worth investing time in (though it's not an excuse of course). Funny thing is, it has received 5 likes. Probably all other readers have missed that for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos) you can see it shows the function declaration as:

```
BOOL SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

That means the functions takes two integer parameters and returns a boolean result.

The return value indicates if the call was successful or not.

If you try to type:

```
BOOL SetCursorPos(10, 20);
```

That doesn’t really make sense as the initial 'BOOL' should be used for declaring a variable to store the result. You could do something like:

```
 BOOL result = SetCursorPos(10, 20);
 if (result == 0) {
     std::cout << “failed to set cursor position”;
 }
```

Or if you don’t care about the return value you can just do nothing with it like this:

```
 SetCursorPos(10, 20);
```

Comment: COOL! That's a great explanation : )

Comment: @barbnar don’t forget to accept this as the answer if it helped